# Javascript update time function causes high CPU

Tags: javascript, performance, date, time

I have the following code that I am using to display the current date and time, and I want it always updated so I have a setInterval to update it every second. This seems to be causing the page to be taking up 25% of the CPU and the memory it takes up just keeps climbing the longer the page is up.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of this?

```
jQuery(function($){
    (function update_time(){ 
        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

        var dt = new Date();
        var hr = dt.getHours() > 12 ? dt.getHours() - 12 : dt.getHours();
        var mi = dt.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getMinutes() : dt.getMinutes();
        var sd = dt.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getSeconds() : dt.getSeconds();
        var div = dt.getSeconds() & 1 ? ":" : " ";

        $('.hour').text(hr);
        $('.minute').text(mi);
        $('.second').text(sd);
        $('.day').text(days[dt.getDay()]);
        $('.month').text(months[dt.getMonth()]);
        $('.date').text(dt.getDate());
        $('.year').text(dt.getFullYear());

        $('.time-divider').text(div);

        setInterval(update_time, 1000);
    })();
});
```

Comment: Yes. Every `setInterval` calls `update_time`, which calls `setInterval`, which calls `update_time`, which calls... Hence the climbing memory usage

Comment: if you want to call a timer each time use setTimeout, otherwise call setInterval outside the function

Comment: Change setInterval() to setTimeout()

Comment: `setInterval` calls `update_time` *every* time 1 second elapses, whereas `setTImeout` would only call `update_time` once, after 1 second

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) instead of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

The comments above have done a good job explaining why, but I'll reiterate.

Your current function will schedule a *new* `setInterval` every time it is called, on top of any existing ones. After just `5` seconds you'll have `32` intervals running. Every second this number doubles.

`setTimeout` executes its callback function *once* after a set amount of time. So after one second the timeout will fire and expire, the function will execute, and a new timeout will be created. Rinse and repeat.

```
jQuery(function($){
    (function update_time(){ 
        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

        var dt = new Date();
        var hr = dt.getHours() > 12 ? dt.getHours() - 12 : dt.getHours();
        var mi = dt.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getMinutes() : dt.getMinutes();
        var sd = dt.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getSeconds() : dt.getSeconds();
        var div = dt.getSeconds() & 1 ? ":" : " ";

        $('.hour').text(hr);
        $('.minute').text(mi);
        $('.second').text(sd);
        $('.day').text(days[dt.getDay()]);
        $('.month').text(months[dt.getMonth()]);
        $('.date').text(dt.getDate());
        $('.year').text(dt.getFullYear());

        $('.time-divider').text(div);

        setTimeout(update_time, 1000);
    })();
});
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Now the memory is staying around 17mb, with 0-1% CPU. Thanks everyone!